# Insert dynamic div as large as body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to via javascript/jQuery, insert a child div to `<body>` that has the same height as `<body>` and that dynamically readjusts its height if the height of body ever grows or shrinks?  Additionally, this div needs to be `position:absolute`.

Currently, assuming that `myDiv` is absolutely positioned, I can do:

```
$('body').append($('.myDiv'))
var bodyHeight = $('body').height()
$('.myDiv').css("height", bodyHeight + "px");
```

However, this will not adjust myDiv's height if body ever grows or shrinks.

Comment: to make a callback on resize-event?

Comment: Sure, that would work, although it would be better if I could do it without additional javascript.

Answer (score 3):

**You may be over thinking this...**

CSS

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0 }
html, body, .mydiv { width:100%; height:100% }
```

jQuery

```
$('body').append($('<div/>').addClass('mydiv'));
```

[Made a fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/88FFY/)